# Interaction with Gravitational Radiation

Tags: gravity, radiation, relativity, gravitational-waves

I have a question about hypothetical gravitational radiation. To put it simply, is there any sort of material or field or other force which can interact with it? I'm thinking about lenses and mirrors for electromagnetic radiation, magnetic fields for alpha and beta particles, etc. Would there, according to our current understanding of gravitational waves/gravitons, be anything analogous to those? As far as I know, there's no reason that gravitational waves/gravitons shouldn't be able to be blocked/reflected/redirected, but if there is a theoretical way to do this I have no idea what it is. I was just thinking about the similarities and differences between gravitational radiation and other types of radiation, and was curious about this. I appreciate any answer!

Thanks!